# WiX shortcut only project

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, shortcut

I have my bootstrapper project and I need to add a shortcut only when another third part msi is selected on bootstrapper's UI. So I end up with another little msi like this (removing not relevant data):

```
<Wix >
<Product >
    <Package />
    <MajorUpgrade />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
            <Directory Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" Name="FolderName">
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>

    <Component Id="ApplicationShortcut" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE" Directory="ApplicationProgramsFolder">
        <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut"
                Name="App"
                Description="desc"
                Target='"[ProgramFiles64Folder]Folder1\Folder2\app.exe"'
                Arguments=' -n name'
                />
        <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveProgramMenuDir" Directory="ApplicationProgramsFolder" On="uninstall" />
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\ACME\App" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
    </Component>

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Shortcuts" Level="1">
        <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcut" />
    </Feature>
</Product>
```

But I get

```
ICE71: The Media table has no entries.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That source doesn't compile anyway because of issues with missing languages, productcodes and so on. It would have helped if you'd posted a complete working example. After fixing those issues and seeing **ICE71**, you basically need to delete mediatemplate and add a proper media entry such as (in angle brackets)

`Media Id="1" Cabinet="product.cab" EmbedCab="yes"`

then all you get is warning `LGHT1079 : The cabinet 'product.cab' does not contain any files`.  If this installation contains no files, this warning can likely be safely ignored.  Otherwise, please add files to the cabinet or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I would just augment the third party MSI with a transform that creates a shortcut when that MSI is installed.  This way you don't have to do anything special in the bootstrapper.